# DiscordJS v13 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')

Tags: javascript, logging, discord.js

Code:

```
const config = require('../../config.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = async(guild, bannerURL, client) => {
    const logChannel = await client.channels.cache.get(config.log_channel_id);
    if (!logChannel) return;
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({ name: guild.name, iconURL: guild.iconURL() })
    .setDescription(`**${guild.name} has banner now!**`)
    .setImage(bannerURL)
    .setColor(config.colour)
    .setTimestamp()
    return logChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
}
```

When adding a banner to the server it gives the error `Unhandled Rejection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')`

The other logging files have the exact same line of code `const logChannel = await client.channels.cache.get(config.log_channel_id);` and it works fine

Adding `console.log(client)` before `const logChannel` returns `undefined`

Comment: Add a `console.log(client)` before the `const logChannel` and update your question with the results please.

Comment: it returns `undefined`

Comment: Ok so then the client isn't being passed through if this is a command, please show how you execute/run that command (in your `messageCreate` listener or where ever) It would say something like `command.execute(x, y, z)` or `command.run(x, y, z)` if not triggered by that, then show how it is triggered and/or where this module imports `(guild, bannerURL, client)` from

Comment: I'm using [this](https://pastebin.com/Q4TEEH4x) command executor

Comment: So the guild does not emit, the client does. so even though you have it labeled guild, it may actually be the client, I would update that code in the paste bin and then define guild using `const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('guildID')`

Comment: I change it to [this](https://pastebin.com/9dUHdsgv) and now it returns  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244437/discussion-between-gh0st-and-m-rald).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below works after we troubleshot the issue.

banner.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'banner',
    description: 'emit update',
    devs: true,
    run: async (guild, message) => {
        guild.emit('guildBannerAdd', message.member);
        message.channel.send('Done ...');
    },
};
```

guildBannerAdd.js

```
const config = require('../../config.json')
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = async (client, member) => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(config.serverID)
    const logChannel = client.channels.cache.get(config.log_channel_id);
    if (!logChannel) return;
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor({
            name: guild.name,
            iconURL: guild.iconURL()
        })
        .setDescription(`**${guild.name} has banner now!**`)
        .setImage(guild.bannerURL())
        .setColor(config.colour)
        .setTimestamp();
    return logChannel.send({
        embeds: [embed]
    });
}
```